# select Unique row value in different column value in SQL

Tags: sql

I have below table in SQL database with column 'name' has same value and column 'Item' has different values.

table :

| Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| A | Good |
| A | Better |
| A | Best |

I would like achieve below result as output.

Result:

| Name | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Good | Better | Best |

Comment: is there a maximum number of items per name ? e.g. 3 ?

Comment: max number of items per name will be 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivoting can done using an aggregated *conditional case expression*.

Your data is missing any column to provide explicit *ordering* to determin which row belongs in which column, which you may wish to address in your actual implementation, the ordering here is arbitrary:

```
select name,
    Max(case when col=1 then item end) Item1,
    Max(case when col=2 then item end) Item2,
    Max(case when col=3 then item end) Item3
from (
    select 
       name, 
       item, 
       Row_Number() over(partition by name order by name) col
    from t
)t
group by name
```

Comment: is this vanilla SQL or some specific flavor? The question from the OP only tags vanilla sql.

Comment: This is standard ansi SQL, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: you're right. Please edit your question so that I can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Here it is, though it will only work for 3 entries and will also sort them alphabetically reversed:

```
select a.name ,
a.item as Item1,
b.item as Item2,
c.item as Item3
from TEMP a,
TEMP b, 
TEMP c
where a.name = b.name and b.name = c.name
and a.item > b.item and a.item > c.item
and b.item > c.item 
;
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a098f/5

### Data

```
create table temp(
  name varchar(20),
  item varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into temp values('A','Good');
insert into temp values('A','Better');
insert into temp values('A','Best');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below when you do not know how many ITEM values would be present for a given NAME, but for that case you'd have to use loop iterator in your code (like iterate from 1 to TOTAL_ITEMS):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST (NAME VARCHAR (10),ITEM VARCHAR(10))
AS SELECT * FROM VALUES 
('A', 'GOOD'),
('A', 'BETTER'),
('A', 'BEST'),
('B', 'GOOD'),
('B', 'BETTER'),
('B', 'BEST');

WITH ITEMS_LIST AS ( 
SELECT NAME, LISTAGG (ITEM, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ITEM DESC) ITEMS,
  COUNT (DISTINCT ITEM) AS TOTAL_ITEMS 
FROM TEST
GROUP BY NAME)
SELECT NAME, 
SPLIT_PART(ITEMS, ',', 1) AS ITEM_1,
SPLIT_PART(ITEMS, ',', 2) AS ITEM_2,
SPLIT_PART(ITEMS, ',', 3) AS ITEM_3,
SPLIT_PART(ITEMS, ',', TOTAL_ITEMS) AS ITEM_N
FROM ITEMS_LIST ORDER BY NAME;
```